# Displacement in ia32 assembly to access an array

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to access two contiguous elements in a array of pointers.
I wrote this two instruction, but when executing it says that I'm trying to access an illegal position:

```
mov esi, strings[ecx*4]
mov edi, strings[(ecx+1)*4]
```

ECX contains an index.

Are they correct or not?
Thank you.

Comment: Try `strings[ecx * 4 + 4]`.

Comment: Must mean your `ecx` holds wrong value. Use a debugger.

Comment: I tried 

    `strings[ecx*4]+4`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
strings[ecx*4]+4
```

and it worked.